# How to only fetch the required data according to a boolean value in Redux Toolkit?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, api, redux, redux-toolkit

i have a query regarding redux toolkit. I want to get the list of array on the click of a checkbox. the array objects has a field called "verified " which is either true or false. According to that, Onclick of the check box i'd like to get all the objects which have the verified value set to true.

Also there isn't any end point called "verified " Which I can pass in the url to fetch a list of only verified array of objects which is want i want to achieve.
array structure looks like this =>

```
{_id(pin):"61bc940989b38d9bc53832e3"
venture(pin):"xyz"
rating(pin):2.3
promotion(pin):0
verified(pin):false
},

{_id(pin):"sjkdfkla38d9bc53832e3"
venture(pin):"xyz"
rating(pin):2.3
promotion(pin):0
verified(pin):true
},

{_id(pin):"blahbdsfasd3"
venture(pin):"xyz"
rating(pin):2.3
promotion(pin):0
verified(pin):true
},
```

below is my reducer and action.

**Action = >**

```
// get all Media Verified Cards
export const getVerifiedCards = createAsyncThunk(
  'verifiedmedia/getall',
  async () => {
    try {
      const header = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          Authorization: `Bearer ${Token_Media_Seller}`,
          ClientId: `Bearer ${ClientId}`
        }
      }
      const response = await axiosInstance.get(
        `/media/?token=${Token_Media_Seller}&client_id=${ClientId}`,
        header
      )

      console.log(response)
      return response.data
    } catch (error) {
      throw error
    }
  }
)
```

**Reducer=>**

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
import { getMediaCards } from '../actions/mediacards'

const initialState = {
  mediaCards: []
}

export const mediacardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'medialist',
  initialState: initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: {
    [getMediaCards.fulfilled.type]: (state, { payload }) => {
      return {
        ...state,
        mediaCards: payload.data
      }
    }
  }
})
```

**My checkbox component =>**

All the exports =>

```
const dispatch = useAppDispatch()
const selector = useAppSelector(state => state.mediacard.mediaCards) //all the items
//onclick function and the action which i want to make to get the verified values
const sortVerified = () => {
 dispatch(getVerifiedCards())
console.log('action dispatched')}
```

JSX=>

```
<div className=''>
<input
type='checkbox'
value={'checked'}
onClick={sortVerified}
/>
</div>
```

**pls help ive been trying differrent methods but i dont what to do :(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well there was no true value so when ever i tried to filter out the array it gave nothing as the output so yeah...